# turning off audio in ubuntu disrupts speakers in windows

Tags: dual-boot, sound, bluetooth

I'm using lenovo thinkpad e480.
I have 2 OS on my laptop. Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10.
Whenever I turn off audio or bluetooth in Ubuntu, I can't turn them on in Windows. I should go to Ubuntu and turn them on and then come back to windows to be able to use them.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: wow! O.o that is Super weird! are you sure? what exact hardware are you using?

Comment: I'm using Lenovo Thinkpad E480.